# Android/Java ArrayList is empty when expecting data to be returned

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase

In my FirebaseHelper.java file I Log.i the arrayList but it shows empty before it is returned. 
Can someone point me in the right direction as to why?

The relevant parts of my code: 
public class Today extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

```
// Variables for the DrawLayout:
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

// Firebase variables:
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseExercisesToday;

// Firebase spinner:
FirebaseHelper helper;

// For storing username such as chrismichaeladams@gmail.com:
String mUsername;

Spinner spinnerExercises;
TextView textViewSpinner;

private String[] exerciseArray;
private ArrayList<String> exerciseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_today);

    // Create instance of Firebase database root:
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    // Get a instance of Firebase database starting at today's date:
    mDatabaseExercisesToday = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("2-14-17");

    /***** Connect UI elements with code: *****/
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_today);


    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    // Pass our database instance to the Firebase Helper class for spinner:
    helper = new FirebaseHelper(mDatabaseExercisesToday);

    exerciseArrayList = helper.retrieve();

    Log.i("ArrayList: ", exerciseArrayList.toString());

    exerciseArray = new String[exerciseArrayList.size()];
    exerciseArray = exerciseArrayList.toArray(exerciseArray);


    // Spinner:
    spinnerExercises = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Exercises2);
    textViewSpinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_spinner2);



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, exerciseArray);

    adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinnerExercises.setAdapter(adapter_state);

    spinnerExercises.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

FireBaseHelper.java:

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
    DatabaseReference db;
    Boolean saved=null;



    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    //SAVE
    public  Boolean save(Exercises exercises)
    {
        if(exercises==null)
        {
            saved=false;
        }else
        {
            try
            {
                db.push().setValue(exercises);
                saved=true;
            }catch (DatabaseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved=false;
            }
        }
        return saved;


    }
    //READ
    public ArrayList<String> retrieve()
    {
        final ArrayList<String> exercisesArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
                Log.i("ArrayListadded1", exercisesArrayList.toString());

            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //fetchDataDelete(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }


        }

        );
        Log.i("ArrayListBefReturn", exercisesArrayList.toString());
        return exercisesArrayList;
    }

    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot snapshot,ArrayList<String> exercisesArrayList)
    {
            exercisesArrayList.add(snapshot.getValue(Exercises.class).getExerciseName());
            Log.i("ArrayList2", exercisesArrayList.toString());


    }

//    private void fetchDataDelete(DataSnapshot snapshot,ArrayList<String> exercisesArrayList)
//    {
//        // Add The exercise to our exerciseArrayList:
//        exercisesArrayList.remove(snapshot.getValue(Exercises.class).getExerciseName());
//
//    }
}
```

Exercises.java:

```
package christopheradams.com.workoutapp8;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

/**
 * Created by Christopher on 2/13/2017.
 */

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Exercises {
        public String exerciseName;
        public String reps;
        public String weight;
        public String username;


        public Exercises(){

        }

        public Exercises(String exerciseName, String reps, String weight, String username){
            this.exerciseName = exerciseName;
            this.reps = reps;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.username = username;
    }

    public String getExerciseName() {
        return exerciseName;
    }

    public String getReps() {
        return reps;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setExerciseName(String exerciseName) {
        this.exerciseName = exerciseName;
    }

    public void setReps(String reps) {
        this.reps = reps;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Also wanted to add a Logcat of my ArrayList output. It is not empty throughout except before it is returned:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this method

```
public ArrayList<String> retrieve()
{
    final ArrayList<String> exercisesArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

    db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
            Log.i("ArrayListadded1", exercisesArrayList.toString());

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //fetchDataDelete(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }


    }

    );
    Log.i("ArrayListBefReturn", exercisesArrayList.toString());
    return exercisesArrayList;
}
```

You create a new empty arraylist here

```
final ArrayList<String> exercisesArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you register a listener, but `fetchData(...)` isn't immediately called. I suppose that you think that this line of code

```
fetchData(dataSnapshot,exercisesArrayList);
```

is immediately executed. But It doesn't work like this. It will be executed when the DatabaseHelper instance will call `onChildAdded(...)`. You register a listener to "listen" some kinds of events. But only when this events occur the listener method will be called. In this case when a child is added the method `onChildAdded(...)` will be called and `fetchData(...)` too.

So you are logging the list but `fetchData(...)` hasn't be yet called.

Comment: I'm using Google Firebase Database. The onChildAdded and onChildChanged are called whenever data is added or changed. But I was also under impression that when it is first loaded it makes a call to onChildAdded, which in turn would call fetchData. I will look at this more, and see if this points me in right direction. Thank you for your reply.